# Facebook Like "Object Invalid value" and URL could not be parsed

Tags: facebook-like, url-parsing

I am getting this error when I did my OG check at facebook
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dreampiece.com.au%2Findex.php%3Fmain_page%3Dproduct_info%26cPath%3D2_7%26products_id%3D459

> Object at URL 'http://www.dreampiece.com.au/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=2_7&products_id=459' of type 'product' is invalid because the given value '' for property 'og:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

This is my page source,

```
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Product Details:    Total Qty: One Pc Materials: Alloy Electroplate &amp; Rhinestones Size: Pendant - 2.5 cm x 1.6 cm; Length&nbsp;-&nbsp;40.6 cm (Ext 7.2 cm) Country of Origin: Japan Colour:&nbsp;Golden&nbsp;" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="DreamPiece Accessories" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="120867161308451" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.dreampiece.com.au/images/Products/m02040.jpg" />
```

Could it caused by the blank og:url? I am using code as below,

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $canonicalLink; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's what's causing it - are you sure your code is actually outputting a value there? It almost certainly isn't if Facebook's crawler is showing nothing in the `og:url` meta tag